# Visual Studio 2010 throws error when creating a Resource File

Tags: visual-studio-2010

This is very strange...I get an error when trying to create a resource file in Visual Studio 2010...I have absolutely no idea how to fix this...tried googling it and came up with nothing.

I tried two different ways...right click on the Class Library Project, click the Resources tab on the left, then click Add default Resource file. A popup comes up with the following:

"Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))

So I tried creating a resource folder and adding a new resource item to that folder...same error.

Has anyone seen this error before or have an idea of where to start to try and fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this before (getting it right now). I get the same error when trying to view class diagrams. In both cases, I only see the problem when I run as administrator. I'm seeing many other similar issues (error loading project properties) running as administrator that other people in my team aren't (even when viewing the same stuff) so I figure it must be something to do with my install.

Update: reinstall worked a charm and I no longer get this error.